# Problems by running celery apply_async from flask app

Tags: python, flask, celery

this is my first project with flask and celery. My Flask app has one process that has long run time, so i try to use Celery to run it asynchron.
Basically code need to generate file on request.
After it is done, user should be redirected to  a page where this file could be downloaded.
As AMQP i use Rabbitmq.
My project has following structure:

```
Project/
|-- flasK.py
|-- asynC.py
|--db.sqlite3    
|
|-- templates/
|   |-- index.html
|   |-- done.html
|   |-- inProc.html
|
|-- |-- static/
    |-- css(empty)
    |-- js(empty)
```

Script to run flask server, flasK.py :

```
from asy import createSAV_2
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect, send_file, send_from_directory, safe_join, abort
from celery.result import AsyncResult

flask_app = Flask(__name__)

@flask_app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #createSAV_2.apply_async((2, 2), queue='test')
        createSAV_2.delay(2, 2)

        return render_template("inProc.html")
    else:
        pass
    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    flask_app.run(port=8080, debug=True)
```

Code to run Celery, asynC.py :

```
from celery import Celery
from time import sleep
from celery.result import AsyncResult
from flask import render_template

app = Celery('asy', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//', backend='db+sqlite:///db.sqlite3')

@app.task(name='createSAV_2')
def createSAV_2 (a, b):
    sleep(5)
    return render_template("done.html")
```

After i run sever and try to simulate request for data, i got this error:

```
[2020-11-01 13:44:41,545: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task createSAV_2[93a094c7-2315-4016-8deb-acffae18f0ef] raised unexpected: AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'app'")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/bbk/Desktop/labelingTool_v1/tool_v0/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 409, in trace_task
        R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/bbk/Desktop/labelingTool_v1/tool_v0/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 701, in __protected_call__
        return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/bbk/Desktop/labelingTool_v1/tool_v0/asy.py", line 11, in createSAV_2
        return render_template("done.html")
      File "/Users/bbk/Desktop/labelingTool_v1/tool_v0/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 136, in render_template
        ctx.app.update_template_context(context)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'app'
```

If i use .apply_async instead of .delay i dont get any error or other massages.

Celery is running, and if im trying to run example code from docs:
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html
then it works fine.

Please let me know if you have any thoughts/suggestions

Comment: Why are you calling render_template() inside celery task ? In your case, why are you using apply_async if you want wait for your task ? Whole purpose of celery+apply_async is to not wait response from the task. You have this error because you try to use Flask context (with template and stuff) from completly unaware python process. To fix this simply remove return line from you task.

Comment: Why are you calling render_template() inside celery task ?
->because i follow code from celery docs.
why are you using apply_async if you want wait for your task ?
->i want to show a page "please wait, file is in process" and after file is done user should be redirected to download page.
To fix this simply remove return line from you task. 
->resulte is same.

Comment: You shouldn't use Celery for this usage I think, Celery is used to run async task on another server or instance. To fix your error, do not use any flask import in `asy.py` and keep using .delay() but in this case celery is useless because you can just call `createSAV_2()` method. If you really want to do that because `createSAV_2` can take a while, you should generate a task with apply_async and implement a loop to wait end of task....So it's the same as using delay().... To summarize I'm not sure Celery is useful in your specific case. Keep it simple at start.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use Celery for this usage, Celery is used to run async task on another server or instance.

To fix your error, do not use any Flask import in asy.py and keep using `.delay()` but in this case celery is useless because you can just call `createSAV_2()` method.

If you really want to do that because `createSAV_2()` can take a while, you should generate a task with `apply_async()` and implement a loop to wait end of task. So it's almost the same as using `delay()`...

To summarize I'm not sure Celery is useful in your specific case. Keep it simple at start.

*(comment converted to answer)*